# What is the charge of each plate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, capacitance

One of the plates is connected to 5v, and the other is earthed. The distance between them is 5cm, and they each have an area of 3cm squared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacitance of a pair of plates is simply the product of the area of each plate and the permittivity of whatever dielectric separates them, divided by the distance between them:

$$C=\varepsilon A/d$$

The charge stored on a capacitor is simply the product of its capacitance and the charge voltage:

$$ Q=CV$$

In your particular example, this is roughly 265 fC.

Comment: What is fC, and when working it out, did you use air as my dielectric? Thanks

Comment: fC is the symbol for the unit femtocoulomb. I used vacuum, but air is pretty close. I also rounded. You should calculate it yourself to verify.

Comment: Please take note of [the homework-type question policies](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714).

Comment: Thanks @RileyScottJacob. Is one of the plates +Q and the other is -Q?

Comment: The formula you quote holds when the separation of the plates is much less than their linear dimensions. It does not apply for the case presented here, where the actual capacitance is over 4 times larger than that given by the formula. Presumably whoever set the question did not know this.